# jQuery progressbar value not setting

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I think I'm missing something really obvious here... must be... but for some reason I can't get my progressbar to display a value that's set in an attribute!

here's my html:

```
<div class="progressBar" data-value="58"></div>
```

and js:

```
$(function () {
    $('.progressBar').each(function () {
        $(this).progressbar();
        //var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        //alert(value);
        $(this).progressbar('option', 'value', $(this).attr('data-value'));
    });
});
```

It displays the bar, but doesn't show any value (i.e. value = 0). If I hardcode a value into the js, it shows fine. If I uncomment the var value and alert line, I get an alert with the value. What am I missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must parse your attr as int :

```
$(this).progressbar('option', "value", parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10));
```

Comment: It's to parse the integer in base 10. If you don't put it, you may have unexpected results.

Comment: For example, type `parseInt('08')` in your console.

Comment: @Tats_innit. and 10 is the default, so I usually not using it, too much noise... but people love to use it for some reason.

Comment: @dystroy. You won't get _"unexpected results"_ for not using 10 for decimals!

Comment: You get "unexpected results" if you don't think about the cases like "08", don't specify the base, and simply expect to have a base 10 parsing... Of course the developer who perfectly knows parseInt expects the results...

Comment: @gdoron you da awesome ninja bruv! thanks! `:)` I was wondering :P

Comment: @dystroy. "08" isn't a valid number, so it shouldn't be there at the first place. I don't argue with you only, I argue with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) as well...

Comment: @dystroy. Thanks! Life saver :)

Comment: @gdoron, 08 is octal base, very valid!

Comment: I first realized this was important when parsing the days in a date like 08/06/2012...

Comment: @arttronics. As I said, "08" isn't a decimal value, so it's not a real scneraio just as `"3748hdfsjhsk"`. Try the base for that string! Invalid input is invalid input, patches won't save you in those cases.

Comment: @gdoron, my point was that you can use `08` for the optional radix parameter when octal base is required. Who says `"3748hdfsjhsk"` is not real input value... it could mean player 3748 has those Scrabble Letters left to use.

Answer (score 2):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/WQnqS/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/WQnqS/1/

**code**

```
$(function () {
    $('.progressBar').each(function () {
        $(this).progressbar();
        //var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        //alert(value);
        $(this).progressbar('option', 'value', parseInt($(this).attr('data-value')));
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(this).progressbar('option', 'value', parseInt($(this).data('value'),10));
```

Comment: @Tats_innit thanks bruv, that's an integer that represents the radix, but that's optional. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

In case, we dont get the first attempt. try like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.progressBar').each(function () { 
    var thisValue = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value')); 
    $(this).progressbar({ value: thisValue });
  });
});
```